# what datatype to use when I want to do bit work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a security field in the column, which will be used to do bit 'banging'

what data type should I use in my migration?

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't have any special support for that. 
You should use `integer`, may be with `:limit => 8`

Comment: bigint isn't rails type, it's mysql type. Rails name (cross-database) is integer with :limit => 8